# Initial reference on Gödel-Löb axiom in Kripke semantic of $GL$

Tags: reference-request, modal-logic

It seems well known in modal logic society that $\Box(\Box p\to p)  \to \Box p$ in Kripke semantics of $GL$ implies well-foundedness of the relation i.e. no infinite ascending chains are allowed.

And validity of $GL$ additionally implies irreflexivity and transitivity of the relation.

But I am wondering what is the initial-like reference for the facts mentioned.

**P.S.** This question may not make clear anything interesting, this is just reference request to experts.

**UPDATE** It seems that Segerberg's thesis is tha earliest reference for the fist fact.

Concerning the second fact I reckon Dick de Jongh has proved this one, that said, unfortunately I could not find any reference.

Comment: Well-foundedness does not imply transitivity. Validity of GL implies transitivity.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek Thank you! I agree, and I am sorry for mistype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper [*Provability: the emergence of a mathematical modality*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20015550) by Boolos and Sambin says (bottom of page $9$) that the first fact was independently gotten by Kripke and Segerberg, and gives the latter's $1971$ thesis as a reference. However, I can't find a copy of Segerberg's thesis online; the only promising link I found, [http://lpcs.math.msu.su/~zolin/ml/pdf/Segerberg_Essay_1971.pdf](http://lpcs.math.msu.su/%7Ezolin/ml/pdf/Segerberg_Essay_1971.pdf), seems broken.

The second fact you mention has trivial first conjunct and false second conjunct (non-transitive frames may still be well-founded), and so I doubt there is a citation for it.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
Yes, I suspected the same about the last fact and I agree with the remark of yours.

Comment: I just realized that that time you addresed the direction well-foundedness -> transitivity. As Emil has noticed that was a mistype, it should be GL -> transitiviry. I recon Dick de Jongh has proved this one, that said unfortunately I could not find a reference.